# Map, applying list in a defined function

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request, map

Suppose I have defined some function (This is arbitrary)

```
 F[alpha_,a_,b_,c_]:=List[alpha,a+b+c]
```

I want to apply this F for a given huge list of sets

```
 {{alpha1, {a1,b1,c1}}, {alpha2, {a2,b2,c2}}, {alpha3, {a3,b3,c3}}}
```

Of course, I can plug this individually, but is there any smart way of plugging these lists into the function $F$ defined above?

For example, I know,

```
   F /@ List[a, b, c]
```

produce

```
 {F[a], F[b], F[c]}
```

So my first trial was just

```
  F /@ {{alpha1, {a1, b1, c1}}, {alpha2, {a2, b2, c2}}, alpha3, {a3, b3, c3}}}
```

But this gives an extra list outside and inside for $\{a1,b1,c1\}$. i.e.,

```
 {F[{alpha1, {a1, b1, c1}}], F[{alpha2, {a2, b2, c2}}], F[{alpha3, {a3, b3, c3}}]}
```

How one can do it wisely?

---

My solution is given as follows :

```
 Map[F[#[[1]], Sequence@@#[[2]]] &, {alpha1, {a1, b1, c1}}, {alpha2, {a2, b2, 
c2}}, {alpha3, {a3, b3, c3}}}]
```

then it produces desired one

Comment: If you rewrite the function as `F[{alpha_,{a_,b_,c_}}]:=List[alpha,a+b+c]`, you can simply map it over your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
F[alpha_, a_, b_, c_] := List[alpha, a + b + c]
```

Let's start with what you didn't ask: If you had:

```
y = {{alpha1, a1, b1, c1}, {alpha2, a2, b2, c2}, {alpha3, a3, b3, c3}}

F @@@ y
```

would give:

> {{alpha1, a1 + b1 + c1}, {alpha2, a2 + b2 + c2}, {alpha3,    a3 + b3 +
> c3}}

For the case in the OP with an extra set of braces:

```
x = {{alpha1, {a1, b1, c1}}, {alpha2, {a2, b2, c2}}, {alpha3, {a3, b3, c3}}}

F[#1, Sequence @@ #2] & @@@ x
```

would deliver the same result.

> {{alpha1, a1 + b1 + c1}, {alpha2, a2 + b2 + c2}, {alpha3,    a3 + b3 +
> c3}}

---

Another variation using operator forms, where I can `Flatten` the arguments first and then use `Apply` down the list.

```
Map[Apply[F]][Map[Flatten][x]]
```

Comment: .. which I now realize is close enough to your recent edit to count as plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Can you explain to me what is the difference for @, @@, @@@? As far as I know @@ is nothing but a replacement, i.e.,  Sequence@@List[a,b,c]=Sequence[a,b],  and @ can be used with /@, Map function, but I am not sure about @@@ x which you used in the answer!

Comment: Define: `t = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}};` and then try: `f@t`, `f /@ t`, `f @@ t` and `f @@@ t` on it. To gain insight on how the `@@` changes an expression, look at `TreeForm`.

Answer (score 2):

Point-free style:

```
list = {{alpha1, {a1, b1, c1}}, {alpha2, {a2, b2, c2}}, {alpha3, {a3, b3, c3}}};
Apply[F]@*Flatten /@ list
```